# Unpredictable behavior of registrator and consul

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have very simple docker-compose config:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  consul:
    image: consul:latest
    hostname: "consul"
    command: "consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect 1   -client=0.0.0.0 -ui  -data-dir=/tmp"
    environment:
      SERVICE_53_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8301_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8302_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8600_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8300_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8400_IGNORE: 'true'
      SERVICE_8500_IGNORE: 'true'
    ports:
      - 8300:8300
      - 8400:8400
      - 8500:8500
      - 8600:8600/udp
    networks:
      - backend

  registrator:
    command: -internal consul://consul:8500
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:master
    depends_on:
      - consul
    links:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    networks:
      - backend


  image_tagger:
    build: image_tagger
    image: image_tagger:latest
    ports:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - backend

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    command: [--auth]
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mongo-data:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.1
#    ports:
#      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwerty
      POSTGRES_DB: ttt
      SERVICE_5432_NAME: postgres
      SERVICE_5432_ID: postgres


networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
```

(and some other services)

Also I configured dnsmasq on host to access containers by internal name.
I spent couple of days, but still not able to make it stable: 
1. Very often some services are just not get registered by registrator  (sometimes I get 5 out of 15).
2. Very often containers are registered with wrong ip address. So in  container info I have one address(correct), in consul  - another (incorrect). And when I want to reach some service by address like myservice.service.consul I end up at wrong container. 
3. Sometimes resolution fails at all even when containers are registered with correct ip.

Do I have some mistakes in config?

Answer (score 0):

So, at least for now I was able to fix this by passing -resync 15 param to registrator. Not sure if it's correct solution, but it works.